# grouping an array by datetime and select max datetime from it

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, datetime

my query is

```
   $fuel_histories = FuelHistory::where('device_id',$Device->id)
           ->where('when','<',$to_date)
           ->where('when','>',$from_date)
           ->select('when','value')
           ->orderBy('when','asc')->get();



     $data = [];
     $dates=[];

     foreach($fuel_histories as $key=>$value):
       $data[$value->when->toDateTimeString()]= $value->value;
     endforeach;
```

I've an array like this, where key is dateTime and value will be a number

```
[2017-09-17 19:53:24] => 6
[2017-09-18 11:53:15] => 1.212
[2017-09-18 11:54:25] => 1.212
[2017-09-18 12:07:40] => 1.212
[2017-09-18 12:07:58] => 8
[2017-09-18 12:25:09] => 12
[2017-09-18 12:25:56] => 19
[2017-09-18 12:37:25] => 17
[2017-09-19 19:54:47] => 1
[2017-09-22 19:54:36] => 2
```

Here I have multiple keys with different time but same date.
I need the latest datetime if some keys have same date and time is in 24hrs format. so keys with same date are

```
[2017-09-18 11:53:15] => 1.212
[2017-09-18 11:54:25] => 1.212
[2017-09-18 12:07:40] => 1.212
[2017-09-18 12:07:58] => 8
[2017-09-18 12:25:09] => 12
[2017-09-18 12:25:56] => 19
[2017-09-18 12:37:25] => 17
```

And the max time is

> 12:37:25

so I need the pair which is

> [2017-09-18 12:37:25] => 17

and finally my expected output is

```
 [2017-09-17 19:53:24] => 6
 [2017-09-18 12:37:25] => 17
 [2017-09-19 19:54:47] => 1
 [2017-09-22 19:54:36] => 2
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Where is your PHP code?

Comment: I got this array after querying and filtering now i'm asking for help to get my expected result,I've tried with timestamp no luck @JustBaron

Comment: Well, you could either create a multi-dimensional array (date, time, value) and then sort by date, then time. Or check the latest time before adding to your existing array.

Comment: can you please remove the down vote :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    '2017-09-17 19:53:24' => 6,
    '2017-09-18 11:53:15' => 1.212,
    '2017-09-18 11:54:25' => 1.212,
    '2017-09-18 12:07:40' => 1.212,
    '2017-09-18 12:07:58' => 8,
    '2017-09-18 12:25:09' => 12,
    '2017-09-18 12:25:56' => 19,
    '2017-09-18 12:37:25' => 17,
    '2017-09-19 19:54:47' => 1,
    '2017-09-22 19:54:36' => 2
];

$dates = [];
$times = [];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $dt = explode(' ', $key);
    if (!in_array($dt[0], $dates)) $dates[] = $dt[0];
    if (!isset($times[$dt[0]]) || strtotime($times[$dt[0]]) < strtotime($dt[1])) {
        $times[$dt[0]] = $dt[1];
    }
}

foreach ($dates as $val) {
    $key = "{$val} {$times[$val]}";
    $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
}

print_r($result);
```

P.S. You should better check the latest time before adding the pair, as JustBaron said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$prevDate = "";
$prevTime = "";
$result = [];
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    list($date,$time) = explode(' ', $key);
    if($date == $prevDate){
        $prevTime = $time;
        continue;
    }
    else if($prevDate !== "") {
        array_pop($result);
        $result[$prevDate." ".$prevTime] = $data[$prevDate." ".$prevTime];
    }

    $prevTime = $time;
    $prevDate = $date;
    $result[$key] = $val; 
}

print_r($result);
```